# Cmake: Automatically mimic folder structure in Visual Studio solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, filter, cmake, solution-explorer

I have a problem regarding Visual Studio solution explorer filter and Cmake. I know that it is possible to specify the FOLDER property for a target in order to organize it in the Visual Studio solution explorer filter. What I wonder however is if there is a way in Cmake so that the Visual Studio solution explorer filter mimics the actual file folder structure without having to set the FOLDER property for each target individually?

I have tried the command:

`set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)`

without any success.

Comment: Starting from CMake version 3.8 the `source_group` command gained a new `TREE` attribute. See if `source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` fits your needs.

Comment: I should have been more explicit in describing the usage of source_group command. `file(GLOB_RECURSE _headers ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)` and `source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PREFIX "Header Files" FILES ${_headers})` should do the trick for headers. And, yes I know `GLOB_RECURSE` is evil.